# Result display problem in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
        A                   B                   C

P_id | name | add     P_id  |  t_id        t_id |  paper  
-----------------     --------------     ------------------ 
  1   sam    ca         1        1           1      asdxa  
  2   john   de         2        1           2      dgfv  
  3   sam    jk         3        2           3      decgf  
  4   sam    ca         4        3           4      ergvtr
```

Now I can easily make a search for Name '**sam**' in Table A group by name, add. and It shows me result like,

**sam  ca

sam  jk**

I am using php and mysql. I want to do some additional task in this:-
   --> Totalcount for the rows..Like
      sam  ca  2
      sam  jk  1
(I am not taking P_id here... just focus on name and add.)

--> Make a link on **2 and 1** (above). so if I click on it. It should displays the related papers    on another html page from **table C**.
     example:    if I click on **2**...  then it should display **asdxa and decgf**.

Comment: You haven't given any code examples of how your php is talking to mysql. What db adapter library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> --> Totalcount for the rows..Like

```
SELECT `name`, `add`, count(`add`) FROM `A` WHERE (`name` = 'sam') GROUP BY `add`;
```

As for the linking, you just link to the page with that ID, and have your php script get the data from the given id in the `C` table.

To select all matching occurences while searching for a name:

```
SELECT  `A`.`name` AS name,  `A`.`P_id` AS aid,  `C`.`t_id` AS cid,  `C`.`paper` AS paper
FROM  `A` , `C` 
WHERE (
    `A`.`name` =  'sam'
)
AND (
    `A`.`P_id` =  `C`.`t_id`
)
```

result:

```
name    aid cid paper
sam     1   1   qwertyui
sam     3   3   zxcvbn
sam     4   4   uytrewq
sam     5   5   hfdsa
```

Which matches the test tables I did in my local environment

Comment: suppose if i click on 2 then it should display two values from table C. now how to fetch these two links...  should i use a temp table for that, (fetch all the data in 1 query and save the link part in temp table). or something else...  I m confused. btw thanks for total count.

Comment: @Gagan np. if my answer was helpful, consider upvoting it (by pressing the up arrow above the answer's score). As for your question, I didn't quite understand, you want to, when clicking on the 2, to fetch both matching results from table `C`?

Comment: Dude i cant upvote ur answer... it requires 15 (minimum) reputation and look at my score  :P   ok just leave the clicking part.. can u plz tell me how to fetch the final result(asdxa and decgf) from table C, if enter the name 'sam'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use for the first task

```
$pdo = new PDO(....);
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT name, add, count(*) from table where name='sam' group by add;')->fetchAll();
if ($result) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
         ......
    }
}
//second
$sql = 'select paper from tableA a inner join TableB b on a.P_id=b.P_id inner join Tablec  c inner join b.t_id = c.t_id where a.p_id=2';
```

//repeat previous statements